# AMCL fails to load map

Tags: navigation, husky, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to navigate around a map that I built using the husky navigation gmapping demo. I have built the map and saved it in my home folder. When I try to run the amcl demo it fails though. I get the code:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[map_server-1]: started with pid [18464]
[ERROR] [1365180853.546403072]: Map_server could not open ~/map1.yaml.
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [18475]
process[move_base-3]: started with pid [18572]
[map_server-1] process has died [pid 18464, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/map_server/bin/map_server ~/map1.yaml __name:=map_server __log:=/home/lemur2/.ros/log/cbfe7674-9e0e-11e2-ac94-0090f5c994bc/map_server-1.log].
log file: /home/lemur2/.ros/log/cbfe7674-9e0e-11e2-ac94-0090f5c994bc/map_server-1*.log
```

When I look for the log file there is nothing there. Any ideas about what is going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60088/amcl-fails-to-load-map/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-05**:
Does the file ~/map1.yaml exist?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-04-05**:
Indeed it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not really a full answer, but I found out that I can have amcl use the /map topic rather than a saved map. I tried that and it no longer gave me the error. amcl is still not working, but that is for another thread.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on 2014-09-12**:
Can you please explain how exactly you use the map topic with amcl?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2014-09-29**:
You need to load a map using the map_server node, and then set the use_map_topic argument in amcl to true.